# How to include dynamically added table rows from javascript when using asp.net after button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

i dynamically added rows depending on the number selected, but i just cant seem to pick data in these rows after trying to submit it to the database. On Button Click it only returns the header row that was predefined in the html file. Is there a way i can have these dynamically created rows read because i really need the data generated from them.

```js
function OptionCount(start, cnt) {

  var elems = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];

  var x = cnt;
  var y = start;
  var i;


  for (i = start; i < x; i++) {


    $('.ObjectiveGen').append($('<tr style="width:100%; height:10%;" class="datarow" name="tm"><td><input type="checkbox" style="position:relative;" class="ia"></td><td style="width:15%;">' + elems[i] + '</td><td id="inp" style="width:70%;"><input type="text" style="width:100%;"/></td><td style="width:15%;"><input type="radio" name="answerradio" /></td></tr>'))

    $('tr td:not(#inp)').addClass("mitu_center");


  }


}
```

```html
<table runat="server" id="objtable" class="ObjectiveGen" border="1" cellpadding=5 cellspacing=2 style="width: 100%; height: auto;">

  <tr id="header_row">
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" id="mainchk" />
    </th>
    <th>Option Value
    </th>

    <th>Answer
    </th>

    <th>Is Answer
    </th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

The asp.net code shown here

```
  protected void mn_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    HtmlTableRowCollection htr = objtable.Rows;

    i = htr.Count;

    foreach (HtmlTableCell tablecell in htr)
    {
        answer = tablecell.InnerText;
    }

     qt.InnerHtml ="Qtn: " + i.ToString() + htr[0].Cells[1].InnerText;

}

enter code here
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime the page is posted back to the server the page get's re-constructed and the values can be evaluated. Because you added the controls on the client side(through javascript) you will not be able to use them on the server side because the server doesn't know anything about those new controls and how to handle them.

As an alternative you can use the [ASP.NET Repeater control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx).This control is very flexible and can be styled to look and feel just like a native HTML table and you will be able to access the `TextBox` values on the server after the post back!

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class TableRepeaterExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var answer1 = new Answer { Option = "A", AnswerText = "" };
            var answer2 = new Answer { Option = "B", AnswerText = "" };
            var answer3 = new Answer { Option = "C", AnswerText = "" };

            Repeater1.DataSource = new List<Answer> { answer1, answer2, answer3 };
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void mn_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            TextBox txtAnswer = item.FindControl("txtAnswer") as TextBox;
            if(txtAnswer != null)
            {
                string answer = txtAnswer.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Answer
{
    public string Option { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Option</th>
                    <th>Answer</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%# Eval("Option") %></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswer" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AnswerText") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="mn_ServerClick" />
    </form>
</body>
```